# How to use JAX-WS for android application

Tags: android, web-services, web-applications, jax-ws

I am developing an android application in which i want to use JAX-WS. The idea is to pull data from a mysql database that i will set up on a server (currently a wordpress website is hosted on that server location). What i want is for my android application to pull some data out of this database that i have set up on the server machine. Will i be needed to write a web app on the server side. How to go about this? I do not properly understand what will be needed for this process and how to set it up. Please help. Is there any step by step tutorial that i can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great tutorial and startup:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

I've been using the same setup as you want to and it works great. The tutorial only goes through the webservice and it's content, then you will have to add database connections to it